# JSP on a paid Web Hosting Server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, server

I'm new to doing JSP and am bit confuse over the configuration. The server that I've just bought recently is a linux based server. I've built this web project in netbeans with tomcat server.

Live files are being put into this folder called `public_html`. I've put the java classes into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. I'm getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error for not being able to find the java class being used in my index.jsp

I'm confused on what to put in the `web.xml` to configure the server to find my java classes? Any help or examples are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is my web.xml:

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<display-name>ThinkAuction</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

For now there are only these, to run it locally I didn't need to touch this file. What are the things do I need to add?

Comment: Post your web.xml file.

Comment: Did you preserve the package structure when you placed the `class` files under `WEB-INF/classes`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes I did. I've placed them into their respective class package.

Comment: I guess your paid web hosting server, is not configured to run java, if you purchased an dedicated server, you can install java or anything you want, to run JSP you need tomcat server(or any server supports java), so in your dedicated server you need to install java, tomcat and then deploy your code to tomcat server under webapps. If your server is not dedicated one call support to ensure that if your server supports java